# selecting right kernel header files for busybox build

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, include, busybox

While building busybox I found some source files are including linux kernel headers.
I added #define __KERNEL__ to select some portion of header file lines. and I also added #define _BUSYBOX_ and inserted #ifndef _BUSYBOX_ in the kernel header file so that some specific part is not selected by the compiler.(I don't know this is the right approach)
The next problem I face is below. It says fd_set is defined twice.

```
In file included from /opt/snakede/lib/gcc/sparc-snake-linux/4.6.2/../../../../sparc-snake-linux/sys-include/linux/thread_info.h:10:0,
                 from /opt/snakede/lib/gcc/sparc-snake-linux/4.6.2/../../../../sparc-snake-linux/sys-include/linux/preempt.h:9,
                 from /opt/snakede/lib/gcc/sparc-snake-linux/4.6.2/../../../../sparc-snake-linux/sys-include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from /opt/snakede/lib/gcc/sparc-snake-linux/4.6.2/../../../../sparc-snake-linux/sys-include/linux/mmzone.h:7,
                 from /opt/snakede/lib/gcc/sparc-snake-linux/4.6.2/../../../../sparc-snake-linux/sys-include/linux/gfp.h:4,
                 from /opt/snakede/lib/gcc/sparc-snake-linux/4.6.2/../../../../sparc-snake-linux/sys-include/linux/slab.h:12,
                 from archival/libarchive/unxz/xz_private.h:16,
                 from archival/libarchive/unxz/xz_dec_bcj.c:11,
                 from archival/libarchive/decompress_unxz.c:36:
/opt/snakede/lib/gcc/sparc-snake-linux/4.6.2/../../../../sparc-snake-linux/sys-include/linux/types.h:23:26: error: conflicting types for 'fd_set'
/opt/snakede/lib/gcc/sparc-snake-linux/4.6.2/../../../../sparc-snake-linux/include/sys/select.h:75:5: note: previous declaration of 'fd_set' was here
```

The message shows fd_set was first defined in sparc-snake-linux/include/sys/select.h and then later again in sparc-snake-linux/sys-include/linux/types.h. Using
echo "" | sparc-snake-linux-gcc -o /tmp/tmp.o -v -x c -
I could see the default include path is

```
#include <...> search starts here:
 /opt/snakede/lib/gcc/sparc-snake-linux/4.6.2/include
 /opt/snakede/lib/gcc/sparc-snake-linux/4.6.2/include-fixed
 /opt/snakede/sparc-snake-linux/sys-include
 /opt/snakede/sparc-snake-linux/include
```

It searches /opt/snakede/sparc-snake-linux/sys-include first before /opt/snakede/sparc-snake-linux/include but the file under /opt/snakede/sparc-snake-linux/include was selected first anyhow. So inserted many #ifndef *BUSYBOX* guard so that the second definitions are block from the compile. The blocked lines are mostly under sys-include directory. I want to know if this is a permissible method (just blocking the second definition) or if there is another nicer, well-defined method for this kind of situation(like I should have instead blocked the first definition-mostly from gcc include header files- and use the files under sys-include directory, which are meant for the target system)
EDIT : using #ifndef *BUSYBOX* I blocked over 20 2nd-time-appearting definitions and am still seeing such errors coming. I don't know if this is the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

a couple of days later, I found that the linux kernel header is defined for linux build so some of the definitions conflict with user definitions. So we need to use 'cleaned header' which the user program can use. To do this I ran
'make ARCH=.. CROSS_COMPILE=.. headers_install INSTALL_HDR_PATH=..
This new linux headers should replace the sparc-snake-linux/sys-include directory. By the way this 'make headers_install' works well before linux2.6 so the headers added later than ver 2.6 should be copied manually to the new header directories. (mostly linux/xx.h asm-generci/xx.h asm/xx.h.  I even had to copy some missing definitions in the new headers from corresponding parts of the sys-include files over.
Hope that helps!